# join, trying to get property of non-object, ->first, ->firstorfail, ->get()

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

I'm quite new to Laravel, sorry if this is a simple question. 
In **panitia** controller if I use `get()` I get:
`Trying to get property of non-object`

If I use `firstOrFail` I get:
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail()`

If I use `first()`, it works, but it will show only the first record

The problems is that this code is fine until I need join table.

**PanitiaController**

```
 public function lihat($username)
{   
    $panitia=DB::table('panitia')
    ->join('detail', 'panitia.id_panitia', '=', 'detail.id_panitia')
   ->where('username', '=', $username)
   ->first();
   return view('admin.lihat',compact('panitia'));

}
```

**panitia view**

```
@foreach ($panitias as $panitia)

     <tr>
         <td>{{ $panitia->id_panitia }}</td>
         <td>{{ $panitia->username }}</td>
         <td>{{ $panitia->nama }}</td>




         <td><a href="{{url('/admin/panitia/lihat',$panitia->username)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
         <td><a href="{{url('/admin/panitia/edit',$panitia->username)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
         <td>

         </td>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

lihat view

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="isbn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Id Panitia</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_panitia" placeholder={{ $panitia->id_panitia}} readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder={{$panitia->username}} readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" placeholder={{$panitia->nama}} readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**solved**

just form problem t_t
thanks everyone for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first()` and `firstOrFail()` will retrieve one record - the first record it finds if it exists.

`firstOrFail()` is also only available for Eloquent. You are using the query builder so that method does not exist.

Finally, `get()` is what you are looking for. It "gets" all matching records, but the query builder's `get()` method returns an array of records.

Your view is not reflecting that. Your view assumes that there is only one record so you are getting the `Trying to get property of non-object` error message. If you get multiple records but you try to do this: `$panitia->id_panitia`, how is the code supposed to know which record's id it's supposed to get? It can't because it's trying to access the id of the array, which doesn't make sense. You need to loop through and change your `lihat` view to something like this:

Note the foreach:

```
@foreach ($panitia as $pan)
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="isbn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Id Panitia</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_panitia" placeholder="{{ $pan->id_panitia}}" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="{{$pan->username}}" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" placeholder="{{$pan->nama}}" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Also, I added quotation marks around the double curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to talk a look at the docs. Especially about eloquent and models. That's much easier, then what you're about the do... https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent